# Date and time to milliseconds in Android

Tags: android, datetime

I am trying to convert given date and time to milliseconds. I am not able to achieve it.

Below is the format of date and time

02 - 07 (DD - MM)
08:50:00 AM (hh mm ss a)

Here is what I have tried:

```
String myDate = "2-05";
String myTime = "08:50:00";
String ampm = "AM";
String toParse = myDate + " " + myTime+" " + ampm;


try
{
    SimpleDateFormat formatter3 = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M hh:mm:ss a"); // I assume d-M, you may refer to M-d for month-day instead.
    Date date;
    date = formatter3.parse(toParse);
    long millis = date.getTime();
    Log.e ("Date in milli",""+millis);
} 
catch (ParseException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} // You will need try/cat
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
08-04 16:50:34.368: W/System.err(6603): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2-05 08:50 AM"
08-04 16:50:34.368: W/System.err(6603):     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
```

Not sure where I am going wrong? Can somebody help me out ?

Thanks!

Comment: ("d-MM hh:mm:ss a"), you forgot a M

Comment: I tried it.not working

Comment: what error did you get? Also I think you should use `dd` instead of `d`

Comment: your code works just fine (resulted miliseconds=10466400000),there may be other error

Comment: How can this be working, the result is parsed as Date and then the milliseconds are taken from it, but these are milliseconds since a certain momnet. I think that the year part is missing, without it, how can you evaluate the date (a date is constructed by and year, a month and the day of the month).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between the exception you're getting and the date you're supplying in the code. The exception says the provided string is `2-05 08:50 AM`, but you should be providing the seconds field as well. It should be `2-05 08:50:00 AM` is there a mismatch somewhere? Are you running old code?

As others have identified, if your month is always two digits, you need to use `MM` instead of `M`